# Android LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished with Fragment transaction: Is this right?

Tags: android, android-fragments, loader, android-handler

Can someone tell me if I understand this correctly? What I have seems to work, but it seems so much more involved than many of the Loader examples... I wonder if I have over complicated things.   I have an activity that uses more than one AsyncTaskLoader. Therefore, I implement inner classes for the LoaderCallbacks instead of having the activity implement the LoaderCallback interface. I read that anonymous inner classes can leak the activity, so I had to create it as a static class with a weak reference to the activity. The onLoadFinished needs to perform a fragment transaction so I need a Handler for that. Again the inner class activity leak issue, so the Handler is a static class. Furthermore, I read that the handleMessage could be called while the Activity is paused, so I need to implement pause and resume methods in the Handler.  Is this really all necessary?

```
 //here are the relavent bits from my activity
private static class SessionListener implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<SessionStatus> {
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mTarget;

    private SessionListener(MainActivity target) {
        this.mTarget = new WeakReference<>(target);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<SessionStatus> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return  new SessionCheckLoader(mTarget.get(), args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<SessionStatus> arg0, SessionStatus arg1) {
        MainActivity target = mTarget.get();

        if (arg1 == MainActivity.SessionStatus.CLOSED && target != null) {
            target.mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SHOW_CLOSED_DIALOG);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<SessionStatus> arg0) {


    }
};

//the handler with pause/resume
 private static class HandlerClass extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mTarget;

    public HandlerClass(MainActivity context) {
        mTarget = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }
    Stack<Message> s = new Stack<>();
    boolean is_paused = false;

    public synchronized void pause() {
        is_paused = true;
    }

    public synchronized void resume()  {
        is_paused = false;
        while (! s.empty())
        {
            sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(s.pop());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (is_paused) {
            s.push(Message.obtain(msg));
            return;
        }
        MainActivity target = mTarget.get();
        if (target != null) {
            if (msg.what == MSG_SHOW_CLOSED_DIALOG) {
                target.sessionDialog();
            }else if (msg.what == MSG_POP_STACK) {
                target.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}

 private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<SessionStatus> sessionCheckListener = new SessionListener(this);
private HandlerClass mHandler = new HandlerClass(this);

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mHandler.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    mHandler.resume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still implement the callbacks in the `Activity`. When calling `initLoader()` provide a unique id for each `Loader`. Use `Loader.getId()` in a `switch` statement in each of the callbacks to determine which `Loader` it is.

Comment: I had looked for an example done in the manner you say where the Loaders have different return types. I found ppl saying to implement different classes instead. I would still like to see such an example, though.

Comment: Try making the `Activity` implement `LoaderCallbacks<Object>` and then cast it to the appropriate loader's type in the `switch-case`.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Is the Handler part correct, then? Is the pause/resume really needed? I guess I am confused because the way I understood it the Handler was needed because you can't commit fragment transactions from the onLoadFinished method, but it looks like a handler could also be called at a bad time for committing fragment transactions?

Comment: onLoadFinished is guaranteed to be called between start / stop so I think you can use transactions. You needn't bother about pause / resume. Where ever possible, put the loader inside the relevant fragment instead of the activity and use the host activity interface pattern to communicate between the fragment and the host activity. This will help restrict it to one loader per activity / fragment and greatly simplify the code.

Comment: But it says right in the javadoc for onLoadFinished: **Note that normally an application is not allowed to commit fragment transactions while in this call, since it can happen after an activity's state is saved.**